# Can I run a webpage-embedded Java Applet on the iPhone's web browser?

Tags: java, iphone, applet

Can I run a Java applet that's been embedded in an  or  HTML tag on an iPhone?
I don't mean as an App but actually through its browser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, as Steve Jobs stated when interviewed about that question in 2007 he answered

> Java's not worth building in. Nobody uses Java anymore. It's this big heavyweight ball and chain.

That's not the truth, but at least you can be sure you can't embed an applet into the browser..

Answer (score 4):

No, the iPhone does not support Java inside or outside the browser.

If you are wondering if it will ever be possible, the answer is almost certainly no. Steve Jobs has been quoted as saying, "Java's not worth building in. Nobody uses Java anymore. It's this big heavyweight ball and chain."

Answer (score 1):

No. No VM is allowed on iPhone OS.

Hence, no java, no flash... nothing but iPhone OS only!

Sad but true.