# Javascript heap size of the browser

Tags: javascript

Is there any java script API to get the current heap size of the browser for chrome, IE & Firefox
My scenario is that I would like to send a big file in chunks, but IE is looking slower in cleaning the memory, so I will start only those many xhrs which IE can handle

Thanks
Prashant

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506064/how-do-you-detect-memory-limits-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect memory limits in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506064/how-do-you-detect-memory-limits-in-javascript)